# OpenAI whisper for realtime transcription

Tags: speech-to-text

I am using [OpenAI whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper) for audio to text conversion. I think this is pretty good for offline speech to text, however, the problem is we want to use it in live transcription, as we use google speech to text.
Whisper expects a audio file, which we can generate using mic. But the problem, is while using realtime live transcription:

- The duration when the audio is posted to server for transcription, the speaker will miss the transcription.
- If audio is recorded during that conversion time, then speaker will not come to know what was spoken before
- And, technically at what interval we should break the recording and send to server?

These practical challenges we are facing in using whisper for live transcription.
Please let me know if there are solutions to this already? Or open ai whisper is yet to mature to this stage? Or some solutions to above problems?